# ASP .NET6 using Windows authentication for Intranet behavior, incognito session won’t logon

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, incognito-mode

To setup ASP .NET portal using Windows authentication I followed the instructions found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

I added NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate` to my project.
(for using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate`)

In ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) I added:

`services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();`

`services.AddAuthorization(options =\> { options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy; });`

In Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) I added:
`app.UseAuthentication(); app.UseAuthorization();`

In launchSettings.json / iisSettings I changed:
`"windowsAuthentication": true, "anonymousAuthentication": false,`

With this in place on browsing towards the portal I found that:
`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` becomes true,
`User.Identity.Name` becomes the `domain\\SAMAccountName` and
`User.Identity.AuthorisationType` becomes Negotiate.

For the intranet site this is perfect, the user got validated as expected.

When I start an incognito session to the portal the browser shows a sign-in box. This is normal behavior because valid credentials are missing. Supplying valid domain-user credentials doesn’t seem to work, it’s keeps on asking for valid credentials. Can someone please point me in the right direction to deal with manually supplied credentials when Windows authentication is configured?

Answer (score 0):

For authorization users who connected from outside domain network
you should use "[Active Directory Federation Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-7.0)" (ADFS)

Microsoft's traditional Active Directory technology stores usernames and passwords and uses them to manage and secure access to computers on a Windows domain. It also provides SSO access to corporate applications. AD Federation Services builds upon this functionality to authenticate users on third-party systems, such as another company's extranet or a service hosted by a cloud provider.

Any way you should learn about "FEDERATION SERVICE"...